# How to keep track of AsynchHttpClient request

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to put do something like this. Any idea how to know which request is corresponding to which project?

```
for (int i=0; i<projects.size(); i++) {
    post("api/Project/getProductionTime", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)
        {
            projects.get(i).setAmount(<things from response>)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can 'freeze' you project before creation an instance of `JsonHttpResponseHandler` and after use it inside onSuccess block:

```
final <project type> project = projects.get(i);
```

just before post().

If not, you can create an Map which can keep one-to-one correspondes between projects and requests.

**Update:**
Please not that I'm unable to test this code as I dont know your project structure.

```
// I assume that both Project and MyJsonHttpResponseHandler has hashCode() and equals() methods
// MyJsonHttpResponseHandler is a subcalss of JsonHttpResponseHandler with hashCode() and equals() methods
private final ConcurrentHashMap<MyJsonHttpResponseHandler, Project> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
...
for (int i=0; i<projects.size(); i++) {
    MyJsonHttpResponseHandler handler = new MyJsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)
        {
            Project project = map.get(this);
            project.setAmount(<things from response>);

            map.remove(this);
        }
    };
    map.put(handler, projects.get(i));
    post("api/Project/getProductionTime", rp, handler);
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested about the Map solution. How can I do it? Like, should I make a separate JsonHttpResponseHandler and map it to a project?

Comment: Thank you @Anton, I wrote my own way to handle the handlers, but the idea is mostly from your answer.